# MavensMate not listing metadata with namespace prefix

Tags: mavensmate

I am using MavensMate sublime text plugin. It doesn't list the apex classes and other metadata which I have packaged in a managed package with a namespace prefix.

Comment: Can you provide more detail. Are you trying to pull the metadata from an org that has the managed installed or are you pulling from the namespaced org? What are the expected results? What are the actual results?

Comment: I am pulling the data from namespaced org. MavensMate doesn't list metadata objects which I have added to managed package. I tried force.com ide and it lists them

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a setting to ignore packages called mm_ignore_managed_metadata
Set this to false.

Comment: @vishesh it looks like this should be marked as the answer?